# Is there matching property for MailMessage Subject like for MailMessage Body (IsBodyHtml)?

Tags: c#, .net, smtpclient, mailmessage

I'm using SmtpClient for sending mails in project and got stuck on mail formatting. Actually, I'm trying to make subject field able to render HTML but without success. Tried with setting SubjectEncoding property of MailMessage to "System.Text.Encoding.UTF8", setting AlternateView on subject with text/html property but nothing was helpful. As I colud see, there is

```
 **IsBodyHtml = true;**
```

property which applied on MailMessage body makes it able to render HTML elements. Even with BodyEncoding set to Encoding.UTF8, without this "IsBodyHtml = true;", body of mail is not able  render HTML so I think that it's key. But there is no built in such property for subject field. Is there another way to make subject field able to render HTML elements?

P.S:  I want to add unicode character (ex. ☑) to subject field to mark email (ex. as good, as bad etc.).

Comment: There is no such thing as HTML subjects. This is restriction of the "mail protocoll".

Comment: If I haven't seen emoticons and symbols in mail subjects so far, I would say that it is impossible :)

Comment: it is very likely the client mail application been customized to convert certain text to whatever u saw in the subject. simple test, can u see the same thing using different email client app?